# Update a table by using cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I'm Unable to update column in `jobs_new` table from `jobs` table by using a cursor even I got correct output in `dbms_output`. It is updating that column with same value below is the code and please help.

```
SET SERVER OUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  CURSOR c_emp IS
    SELECT
      a.job_id,
      a.max_salary,
      b.job_id
    FROM jobs a, jobs_new b
    WHERE

  a_jobid VARCHAR2(100);
  b_jobid  VARCHAR2(10);
  l_salary NUMBER;
BEGIN

  OPEN c_emp;

  LOOP
    FETCH c_emp INTO a_jobid, l_salary, b_jobid;
    -- enter code here
    EXIT WHEN c_emp%NOTFOUND;

    UPDATE jobs_new
    SET max_salary = l_salary
    WHERE b_jobid = a_jobid;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_salary);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_emp;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to be incomplete, nothing is there after where condition,

Problem is here

```
update jobs_new set max_salary = L_SALARY where b_jobid = a_jobid;
```

it should be

```
update jobs_new set max_salary = L_SALARY where job_id = a_jobid;
```

But considering job_is as unique key, you don't have to use cursor for this operation. you can have a single Update statement as

```
update jobs_new a set a.max_salary = (select b.max_salary
                                        from jobs b 
                                       where b.job_id = a.job_id);
```

Comment: yes, this update statement is working fine for me so cant we users cursors for these kind of situations?

Comment: Cursors should be used if there is some complex calculation or operation on data. Although useful, cursors just increases overhead on database and the way you are updating using the cursor, it increases context switches.